# Why the height and width is not shown on web page?

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have a web page, in which I'm creating an image tag using `var img = document.createElement("img");` but in the next line I am also using the elements height and width but it doesn't work properly:

```
 var base64_string = response.response.data[i].data;
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 // added `width` , `height` properties to `img` attributes
 img.css({
      'width' : '100px',
      'height' : '100px'
 });
 img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_string;
 var preview = document.getElementById("images");
 preview.appendChild(img);
```

Why is the height and width not working in this code? Please can I have suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `css()` method in DOM. You seem to be confusing it with jQuery.

You can modify the `.style.width` and `.style.height` properties of the image element instead.

Comment: he included the jQuery tag so I suspect there is another issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif — They included actual code too. `var img = document.createElement("img");` We can see that `img` is a DOM object and not a jQuery object. Including the jQuery library doesn't modify the DOM API, it isn't like Prototype.js.

Comment: @Quentin can we convert this created element into anchor tag or click able?

Comment: If it is an anchor then it wouldn't be a link any more. You could put the image inside a link (or a button).

Comment: @Quentin can you please tell me how? or I have to put an other question for it

Comment: The same way you put the image inside preview.